# Authorization with Codeigniter+CSRF+uLogin error

Tags: codeigniter, authorization, csrf

Set authorization module uLogin for Codeigniter
  http://ulogin.ru/constructor.html

However, it causes an error (`"The action you have requested is not allowed."`) if  enabled CSRF protection.

If the protection is turned off, everything works fine.

If protection is enabled, then after logging and automatic refresh the current page fails.

Apparently due discrepancies passed token. How to solve this problem?

Answer (score 1):

The CodeIgniter CSRF has a setting that may be causing your problem.  In /config/config.php, the setting `$config['csrf_expire']` determines how long a CSRF cookie is good for.  For example, if that setting was at 300 (5 minutes), and you refreshed the login page but then didn't try to sign in for 10 minutes, you would receive the error `"The action you have requested is not allowed."` since the CSRF cookie expired 5 minutes ago.

Essentially, that error is likely coming from the CodeIgniter CSRF cookie being expired.  That cookie is set when a page is loaded, so if a page with a form sits there for longer than the `$config['csrf_expire']` setting, you must refresh the page before submitting the form or you will receive that error.  To avoid getting the error as often, try increasing the size of `$config['csrf_expire']`.

Also, if you use the CodeIgniter [form helper](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/helpers/form_helper.html), the hidden CSRF input will be automatically generated.

Comment: Thank you. All settings are correct. The problem is not in the settings.

Comment: The problem is absolutely what explained above.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with the linked "module", but you'll need to add a hidden field to your login form, containing the CSRF validation data, like this:

```
<input type="hidden"
    name="<?=$this->security->get_csrf_token_name();?>"
    value="<?=$this->security->get_csrf_hash();?>"
/>
```

Comment: Thank you. When the CSRF protection in the form of hidden fields are automatically added.
The problem is not the lack of fields, and that the authentication token is returned by the server is not valid.

Comment: What authentication token?